# Issue when using sed in combination with read

Tags: bash, macos, sed, bsd

I am having a problem with sed. Basically, I want to insert some text after a match a small piece of Java code after a match. It seems to be somehow interpreted as something else and ends up failing.

Consider the following basic example that does what I want:

```bash
match="string_I_want_to_match"
str_i_want_above="str I want above"

echo $match | sed -e "/$match/i \\
$str_i_want_above"
```

outputs what I want:

```bash
xyzt
string_I_want_to_match
```

However, if I use `read` to create a multiline string, it fails with an obscure error. Consider the following example:

```bash
match="string_I_want_to_match"

read -r -d '' str_i_want_above <<- 'EOF'
> I
> Want
> This
> Above the match
EOF

echo $match | sed -e "/$match/i \\
$str_i_want_above"
```

I expect

```bash
I
Want
This
Above the match
string_I_want_to_match
```

but instead I get

`sed: 3: "/string_I_want_to_match ...": invalid command code W`

It's somehow failing when trying to interpret the second line. I have isolated this to be a problem with `read` but if I'm wrong, I'd like to understand why and to fix this.

I'm using BSD sed on mac 12.6. I would like to achieve this with `sed` and `read` because I need to do in-place replacing and this is going to be a larger script where I need to do several in-place insertions of multiline strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a `\` before the line breaks in replacement, so you may use:

```bash
match="string_I_want_to_match"

echo "$match" | sed "/$match/i \\
> ${str_i_want_above//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}
> "

I
Want
This
Above the match
string_I_want_to_match
```

Here:

- `${str_i_want_above//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}`: Inserts `\\` before each line  break

[**<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>**](https://ideone.com/SLhwZM)

Comment: this indeed works. Thanks. could you elaborate a bit further why is this necessary? And Why if I manually insert ``\`` or ``\\`` within the heredoc it doesn't work (one ``\`` gives the same error and two ``\\`` works but inserts one spurious ``\``)

Comment: It is sed's requirement to escape using \ before a line break

Comment: To answer your second part, if you insert single \ before line break in here-doc then also it works pretty well. (I have tested that on Mac)

Comment: Correct, I have noticed I had an error when trying. Thank you.